# what libraries can i use to make http connections in visual basic? like cURL library for VB?

Tags: vb.net

what libraries can i use to make http connections in visual basic? like cURL library for VB ?

i am looking for something like cURL for visual basic.

VB.NET ! sorry should've made it clear. i also want to know, if i can submit web forms with VB.

Comment: VB.NET ! sorry should've made it clear. i also want to know, if i can submit web forms with VB.

Answer (score 0):

If it is VB6, you may want to take a look at this: [libcurl for VB6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcurl-vb/)

For .NET, take a look at the [WebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). Example of requesting data here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx, example of sending data here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx